# Error when initializing trac_ik on Noetic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have used TRAC-IK on ROS Melodic and Kinetic and everything works fine.

However, when I ported the same code to ROS Noetic, I found that TRAC-IK could not be initialized, i.e., I got this error

```
 Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)
```

when running to

```
  TRAC_IK::TRAC_IK tracik_solver(chain_start, chain_end, urdf_param, timeout, eps);
```

To make sure it wasn't an error in my code, I ran [test.cpp](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/master/trac_ik_examples/src/)  separately and ran into the same problem.

I'm not sure what is causing this error, or if I'm missing the installation of other libraries. But for now, my code builds fine.

Looking forward any reply!

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409387/error-when-initializing-trac_ik-on-noetic/) by [JohnDoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/92256/johndoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the error is coming due to an incorrect installation of  [trac_ik](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/master/). To answer you completely, I tested it in ROS Noetic and found it working. Please see below:

1. **Install trac_ik:** Please install from pre-built binaries as shown below:

   ```
    $ sudo apt install ros-noetic-trac-ik
   ```
2. **Install dependency to run an example:** We do not need this package. But here, I want to run an example to confirm trac_ik.

   ```
    $ sudo apt install ros-noetic-pr2-description
   ```
3. **Run example:** The [pr2_arm.launch](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/9d22477e70d64df75720ec99066cb03ee813ec3d/trac_ik_examples/launch/pr2_arm.launch#lines-11) uses [`TRAC_IK::TRAC_IK tracik_solver(chain_start, chain_end, urdf_param, timeout, eps)`](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/9d22477e70d64df75720ec99066cb03ee813ec3d/trac_ik_examples/src/ik_tests.cpp#lines-51)

   ```
    ravi@dell:~$ roslaunch trac_ik_examples pr2_arm.launch 
    ... logging to /home/ravi/.ros/log/a428d09e-64be-11ek-b98a-bhc0cd415369/roslaunch-dell-13219.log
    Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
    Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
    Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

    started roslaunch server http://dell:36633/

    SUMMARY
    ========

    PARAMETERS
     * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
     * /rosdistro: noetic
     * /rosversion: 1.15.14
     * /trac_ik_tests/chain_end: r_wrist_roll_link
     * /trac_ik_tests/chain_start: torso_lift_link
     * /trac_ik_tests/num_samples: 1000
     * /trac_ik_tests/timeout: 0.005
     * /trac_ik_tests/urdf_param: /robot_description

    NODES
      /
        trac_ik_tests (trac_ik_examples/ik_tests)

    auto-starting new master
    process[master]: started with pid [13259]
    ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

    setting /run_id to a428d09e-64be-11ek-b98a-bhc0cd415369
    process[rosout-1]: started with pid [13284]
    started core service [/rosout]
    process[trac_ik_tests-2]: started with pid [13287]
    [ INFO] [1668500629.439007277]: Using 7 joints
    [ INFO] [1668500629.440011185]: *** Testing KDL with 1000 random samples
    [ INFO] [1668500629.440163447]: 0% done
    [ INFO] [1668500630.509473437]: 90% done
    [ INFO] [1668500630.632576062]: KDL found 859 solutions (85.9%) with an average of 0.0011914 secs per sample
    [ INFO] [1668500630.632594903]: *** Testing TRAC-IK with 1000 random samples
    [ INFO] [1668500630.632938700]: 0% done
    [ INFO] [1668500631.733434004]: TRAC-IK found 955 solutions (95.5%) with an average of 0.0010914 secs per sample
    [trac_ik_tests-2] process has finished cleanly
    log file: /home/ravi/.ros/log/a428d09e-64be-11ek-b98a-bhc0cd415369/trac_ik_tests-2*.log
    ^C[rosout-1] killing on exit
    [master] killing on exit
    shutting down processing monitor...
    ... shutting down processing monitor complete
    done
   ```

### Note

Please read below if you get the following error with `pr2_arm.launch` file

```
RLException: Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: no such command [['/opt/ros/noetic/share/xacro/xacro.py', '/opt/ros/noetic/share/pr2_description/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro']]. 

Param xml is <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find pr2_description)/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro'"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Please change `xacro.py` to `xacro` at line#8 of `/opt/ros/noetic/share/trac_ik_examples/launch/pr2_arm.launch` file as suggested [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/366957/problem-with-xacro-invalid-param/?answer=366979#post-id-366979).

### Update

With "chain_start", "chain_end", as "base_link", and "tool0" respectively, the IK test of [kuka lbr iiwa](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/tree/melodic-devel/kuka_lbr_iiwa_support/urdf) robot using trac_ik works smoothly. Below is the `kuka_lbr_iiwa.launch` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="num_samples" default="1000" />
  <arg name="chain_start" default="base_link" />
  <arg name="chain_end" default="tool0" />
  <arg name="timeout" default="0.005" />

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find kuka_lbr_iiwa_support)/urdf/lbr_iiwa_14_r820.xacro'" />

  <node name="trac_ik_tests" pkg="trac_ik_examples" type="ik_tests" output="screen">
    <param name="num_samples" value="$(arg num_samples)" />
    <param name="chain_start" value="$(arg chain_start)" />
    <param name="chain_end" value="$(arg chain_end)" />
    <param name="timeout" value="$(arg timeout)" />
    <param name="urdf_param" value="/robot_description" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

This is how, I executed it:

```
$ roslaunch trac_ik_examples kuka_lbr_iiwa.launch 
... logging to /home/ravi/.ros/log/648856b2-655b-11ed-b98a-bfc0cd455360/roslaunch-dell-115393.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
started roslaunch server http://dell:44651/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.14
 * /trac_ik_tests/chain_end: tool0
 * /trac_ik_tests/chain_start: base_link
 * /trac_ik_tests/num_samples: 1000
 * /trac_ik_tests/timeout: 0.005
 * /trac_ik_tests/urdf_param: /robot_description

NODES
  /
    trac_ik_tests (trac_ik_examples/ik_tests)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [115433]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 648856b2-655b-11ed-b98a-bfc0cd455360
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [115460]
started core service [/rosout]
process[trac_ik_tests-2]: started with pid [115467]
[ INFO] [1668567873.100935324]: Using 7 joints
[ INFO] [1668567873.102060585]: *** Testing KDL with 1000 random samples
[ INFO] [1668567873.107102190]: 0% done
[ INFO] [1668567874.109234688]: 30% done
[ INFO] [1668567875.367298698]: 70% done
[ INFO] [1668567876.307079837]: KDL found 400 solutions (40%) with an average of 0.00320388 secs per sample
[ INFO] [1668567876.307104300]: *** Testing TRAC-IK with 1000 random samples
[ INFO] [1668567876.307449347]: 0% done
[ INFO] [1668567876.837260447]: TRAC-IK found 996 solutions (99.6%) with an average of 0.000525585 secs per sample
[trac_ik_tests-2] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/ravi/.ros/log/648856b2-655b-11ed-b98a-bfc0cd455360/trac_ik_tests-2*.log
^C[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JohnDoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/92256/johndoe/) on 2022-11-15**:
Thank you for your reply and detailed explanation. I followed your instructions and was able to see the same verification results.

However, this is not what I want.

When I run [test.cpp](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/master/trac_ik_examples/src/) via C++ in IDE and launch the robot description in another terminal, I get the error mentioned above, which does not happen with the `ROS Melodic`.

I am using the [kuka lbr iiwa robot](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/tree/melodic-devel/kuka_lbr_iiwa_support/urdf). For the main function of my test.cpp, I just changed the following parameters based on the sample.

```
nh.param("chain_start", chain_start, std::string("base_link"));
nh.param("chain_end", chain_end, std::string("tool0"));
nh.param("urdf_param", urdf_param, std::string("/robot_description"));
```

Besides, the rest is exactly the same as the original test.cpp.

Would you please try to call `trac-ik` in this way?

Thanks!

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-11-15**:
Please see the "Update" section in my answer above. Basically, it works fine with your parameters as well. However, in your computer, most probably the `trac_ik` is broken. Please install it as mentioned in the answer above.

**Comment by [JohnDoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/92256/johndoe/) on 2022-11-15**:
Thank you for your patient response, which I greatly appreciate.

I have tried all your instructions and everything goes well. However, I found the problem when I was trying to share a minimally reproducible example for you.

For my original project, there are many components in the `find_package` of `CMakeList`, e.g. `kdl_parser`, `trac_ik_lib`, `nlopt`, `visualization_msgs`, and so on.

For the minimal reproducible example project, I just included `kdl_parser` and `trac_ik_lib`, and I found that the error encountered above disappeared.

Through repeated testing, I found that in `ROS Noetic`, the `nlopt lib` and `trac_ik_lib` conflict with each other, which causes the error I raised in the question and does not occur with `ROS Melodic`.

Anyway, thanks for the guidance and I was able to find this problem in my attempt.

PS: I installed `nlopt` and `trac_ik_lib` by `sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-****`.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-11-15**:
I am glad that you made it work. Sometime, creating a " minimally reproducible example" helps to filter the issue, as you did. BTW, the `nlopt` is automatically installed when using `sudo apt install ros-noetic-trac-ik`. So, you don't need to worry about it. Otherwise, you have to install `libnlopt-dev` and `libnlopt-cxx0`. I have tested both approaches in Noetic (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) and found working.

Finally, if this answer helped you to found the issue and the problem is resolved, may I request you to (1) upvote, and (2) mark this answer as accepted? Please look at the top left corner of this above above.

**Comment by [JohnDoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/92256/johndoe/) on 2022-11-16**:
No problem, I've marked this as the answer.

Thanks again for your kindness!